# Microsoft Sync Remote Files?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, file-transfer

Basically I have two parts of my application that I need help with.

1. I need to send an ini containing some preferences over a TCPClient socket to a client. How might I do this?
2. I need to scan a folder on the client side and see what is different from the folder on the server, then send the changed files.

Thanks very much,
Christian

EDITS

Potential leads:

1. [Microsoft Sync Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623) - They mention that this can be used for remote files, but I have not found any explanation or code samples.
2. [FileSync on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filesync/) - Looks
   good, but does it have network sync?

Comment: I found this, would it be a good thing to use for question 2? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623

Comment: Only browsed through the article but I didn't find anything on remote synchronization. Otherwise it looked like a treat. Update: it says: "The file synchronization provider enables rich archiving scenarios by allowing for a one-way synchronization of files from the primary PC or hard disk to the backup PC or hard disk.". Might be just what you are looking for!

Comment: To everyone looking at this.. I now need to find how to use microsoft sync remotely.

Comment: This has been solved over and over again in the past ten years.  Gut answer to 'how can we use the Internet effectively?'  Erm, how about sharing files?  They've come and gone, the clear winner seems to be DropBox.  It's done pretty right, it doesn't try to remind you over and over again "I'm doing something special!"  It has an API.  You can google it as well as we can.

Comment: Thats mobile. Im not doing a mobile app. Please actually try to help rather than speak in metaphorical terms to make yourself look nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I actually fixed this:

Client connects to server (or webserver!)
Client downloads XML with file structure, including MD5 of each file.
Client figures out which files need to be redownloaded.
New files are downloaded from server (or webserver!)

Honestly all of this can be done through a webserver approach, simply host all the files and the XML structure file on a normal webserver and then have the client use these files.

~Christian

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with Microsoft sync framework.

Here is a code sample for doing file synchronisation: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/File-Synchronization-516e3ad7

Comment: Would this allow for remote sync?

Comment: I see this, but the code samples show destinationDirectory and sourceDirectory, indicating it can only work over connected drives I.E. a hard drive or a thumbdrive using file write methods.

Comment: I quote, however havent been able to find a code sample, " The directories to synchronize can be local or remote; they do not have to be of the same file system." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd937565(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: @ChristianStewart how did you fixed this issue between remote and local folders?